# How do I type different return types that are required to be of certain type elsewhere?

Tags: typescript

How do I type different return types that are required to be of certain type elsewhere? I have a function `formatData` that is modifying the shape of an object that will be used when I call other functions; `update` & `create`. `update` & `create` expect specific types while my `formatData` will return either type.

Ultimately, it's my CreateType and UpdateType that conflict due to the type of `id`.

```
// Create type that may or may not have an id, could also be null.
interface CreateType {
  id?: string | null;
  name: string[];
}

// Update type that must have id
interface UpdateType {
  id: string;
  name: string[];
}

// massage data into desired response.
interface ExampleReturnType {
  details: CreateType | UpdateType; // details can be one of two types
  friends: string[];
}

interface InputParams {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
  friend: string;
}

function formatData(input: InputParams): ExampleReturnType {
  const { id, name } = input;
  return {
    details: {
      ...(id ? { id } : ""), // if there is an id, include it on the object otherwise do not.
      name: [name],
    },
    friends: [input.friend],
  };
}

// do something with the parsed data that will have an id
function update(input: UpdateType) {
  //...
}

// do something the the parsed data that probably wont have an id
function create(input: CreateType) {
  //...
}

const createInput = { name: "Tony", friend: "some Friend" };
const updateInput = { id: "123", name: "Tony", friend: "another friend" };

const createObject = formatData<CreateType>(createInput);

const updateObject = formatData<UpdateType>(updateInput);
create(createObject.details);
update(updateObject.details);
```

I get the following error:

```
`Argument of type 'CreateType | UpdateType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UpdateType'.
  Type 'CreateType' is not assignable to type 'UpdateType'.
    Types of property 'id' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)`;
```

Another way I've attempted to type the return type is to use generics, but I've only been able to get similar and other errors.

```
interface ExampleReturnType<T> {
  details: CreateType | UpdateType; // details can be one of two types
  friends: string[];
}

function formatData<T>(input: InputParams): ExampleReturnType<T> {
  const { id, name } = input;
  return {
    details: {
      ...(id ? { id } : ""), // if there is an id, include it on the object otherwise do not.
      name: [name],
    },
    friends: [input.friend],
  };
}

create(createObject.details);
update(updateObject.details);
```

Comment: Not an answer but you can do `...(id && { Id })` for optional spread operator depending on a condition. Also if Id is 0 in your check it won't include it. Maybe `id != null` would be better

Comment: Oh yeah, the logical AND is cleaner, thanks. I know `id` will be a `string` or `undefined`, therefore I know I can accept truthy values.

Comment: You can use like [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8K7PW); does that meet your needs? If not please specify what's missing.  Otherwise I can maybe write up an answer.